# Insert multiples rows/columns - PostgreSQL 9.2

Tags: postgresql, insert

I've got a table that has several columns, But I need to insert data into two columns of that table.
I need to add data into those columns, from a select statement.

Would it be something like:

```
INSERT INTO dm.billables_links (billable_id, mobiuser_id)
SELECT billable_id FROM junk.wm_260_billables2 WHERE info ilike '%Alisha%'
SELECT id FROM public.ja_mobiusers WHERE name_first LIKE 'Alisha%' AND name_last LIKE 'Dson%'
```

It has to be in the same transaction because the mobiuser_id must go to the selected billable_id on the first select.

How can I do that?

> 1 - Select billable_id from dm.billable
>
> 2 - Select mobiuser_id from
>   ja_mobiusers
>
> 3 - Insert the billable_id and the mobiuser_id to the
>   dm.billables_links table.

I've a CONSTRAINT on the target table: (That's why I need to get it done at the same time. So I won't get errors like:

> ERROR:  new row for relation "billables_links" violates check
>   constraint "cc_one_and_only_one_target"

```
ALTER TABLE dm.billables_links
  ADD CONSTRAINT cc_one_and_only_one_target CHECK ((("customer_id" IS NOT NULL)::integer + ("role_id" IS NOT NULL)::integer + ("mobiuser_id" IS NOT NULL)::integer) = 1);
```

This is related to my previous question - Which I've asked to be deleted because have done the wrong question and it has been confused.
[INSERT INTO + Selects - PostgreSQL 9.2](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/132334/insert-into-selects-postgresql-9-2)

**UPDATE 1:** This is an example of what I need

1 - select the billable_id: (**SELECT1**)

```
SELECT billable_id FROM junk.wm_260_billables2 WHERE info ilike '%Alisha%'
```

2 - select the mobiuser_id: (**SELECT2**)

```
SELECT id FROM public.ja_mobiusers WHERE name_first LIKE 'Alisha%' AND name_last LIKE 'Dadryl%'
```

3 - Insert those two data into the dm.billables_links table (EXAMPLE):

```
INSERT INTO dm.billables_links (billable_id, mobiuser_id) VALUES (**SELECT1**, **SELECT2**);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's *guaranteed* (like you commented on your previous question) that each `SELECT` returns *exactly* 1 row, the simplest way to combine both would be to just nest one `SELECT` within the other:

```
INSERT INTO dm.billables_links (billable_id, mobiuser_id)
SELECT billable_id
    , (SELECT id
       FROM   public.ja_mobiusers
       WHERE  name_first LIKE 'Alisha%'
       AND    name_last LIKE 'Dson%') AS foo  -- alias irrelevant
FROM   junk.wm_260_billables2
WHERE  info ILIKE '%Alisha%';
```

If there can be 0 - n results per `SELECT`, it gets more complex. You would have to define what the result should look like for each possible combination.

Note that you get no row (nothing inserted) if the outer `SELECT` finds nothing, but a NULL value for the second column if the nested `SELECT` finds nothing.

Or you could just use two subqueries:

```
INSERT INTO dm.billables_links (billable_id, mobiuser_id)
VALUES (
  (SELECT billable_id
   FROM   junk.wm_260_billables2
   WHERE  info ILIKE '%Alisha%')
, (SELECT id
   FROM   public.ja_mobiusers
   WHERE  name_first LIKE 'Alisha%'
   AND    name_last LIKE 'Dson%')
   );
```

Now you get NULL for each column where nothing is found, and an error if more than one row is found.

I seriously doubt that an `ILIKE` expression can guarantee a single result row.

---

Aside: your constraint would be faster and cleaner this way - though more verbose:

```
ALTER TABLE dm.billables_links ADD CONSTRAINT cc_one_and_only_one_target
CHECK (customer_id IS NOT NULL AND role_id IS     NULL AND mobiuser_id IS     NULL
    OR customer_id IS     NULL AND role_id IS NOT NULL AND mobiuser_id IS     NULL
    OR customer_id IS     NULL AND role_id IS     NULL AND mobiuser_id IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: @JohnThomaz: You can use `LIMIT 1` to allow at most one resulting row per `SELECT`. But are you willing to pick an arbitrary winner from a resulting set?

Comment: that's exactly what I need - I just added: **WHERE  info ILIKE '%Alisha%' AND account_id = 32152**

Comment: @JohnThomaz: Also note the added aside about your constraint.